# Assign dataset (.xsd) to existing report (.rdlc)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dataset

How to I assign dataset to the existing report?

I went a little bit other way around then you usually do it - first build RDLC and then got my dataset done, however now I'm clueless how to assign that dataset to my report. In properties window whatever I select Body, Report or Tablix - I can't find anything that would allow me to choose dataset.

There was this screen (wizard) with drop-down that allowed you to pick dataset, but in no way I can find it. Anyone can help how to trigger it again? Or help me to assign my dataset to report in any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the `Report Data` properties Window.

With an RDLC report open press the <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+D</kbd> or select the menu View then `ReportData`

There you find the DataSet node where, a right click, opens the `Add New Dataset` wizard

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you :) I keep on forgetting about that Report Data screen :/.

Comment: As a new user of this tool, I have just finished cursing for the same reason. Good luck, I think we both need it

Comment: Aii, any hint how else to get this if Ctrl+Alt+D has been remapped by resharper? I went into the xml of the report and changed the dataset by hand

Comment: @Ruskin That shortcut will not open the XML of the RDLC file. To open the XML you right click on the RDLC file, choose open with... and select XML editor option (or use an external tool directly from the filesystem) Keep a backup copy.... ReportViewer does not take well  wrongly made manual changes. Now if I can only fix that crash every time I try to Add a New Dataset I will be an happy coder.